# Unable to get a second Spring MVC app to run in STS.

Tags: spring-mvc, mapping

I'm using this tutorial:

http://blog.springsource.org/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/

to run a Spring MVC app using spring's tool suite 3.0 (sts).

It works fine when one app (BareMvc) is deployed, and using this url:

http://localhost:8080/BareMvc/

However, if I attempt to deploy a second one (AnotherMvcProject), using this url:

http://localhost:8080/AnotherMvcProject/

It returns a 404 Page not found error, and the console shows this error message:

ARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/AnotherMvcProject/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Also, the log is showing that it's being deployed:

```
Jan 3, 2012 2:24:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor AnotherMvcProject.xml from /Users/myname/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.6.1.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/conf/Catalina/localhost
```

Here's the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here's the ServletContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="xyz.mvc.project" />

</beans:beans>
```

Here's the Controller code:

```
/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! the client locale is "+ locale.toString());

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }

}
```

The code is identical to BareMvc, with the exception of the package name. xyz.sample.baremvc vs. xyz.mvc.project.

I'm not clear on how the mapping from the application name to the servlet engine is specified. It looks like it might be pom.xml, the project, but these are also consistent:

```
groupId=xyz.sample
m2e.projectName=BareMvc

groupId=xyz.mvc
m2e.projectName=AnotherMvcProject
```

I'm stumped. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference - just cleaning out the project solved the problem.